# Start vlc minimized from command line

Tags: command-line, vlc, minimize

This is what Im trying..

```
sleep 2700 && vlc --start-time=29 --stop-time=60 ~/Desktop/Interstellar.mp3
```

from my shell script(may randomize the target file in future)

did use
`--qt-start-minimized`
option too,

did checked vlc start minimized in the Vlc Player itself, couldn't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start `vlc` with the `--advanced` option from the command line. `vlc --advanced`

Then go to *Tools* -> *Preferences*.

Then down to `Interface` then `Main interfaces` then `Qt`.

Then on the right choose "Start VLC with only a systray icon"

Click *Save* at the bottom when completed.

[image]

Click on "Simple" for the `Show settings` in the lower left.  Then select "Allow only one instance" and click *Save* so that you are not duplicating the systray icon.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: The thing is, once I set this option "Start VLC with only a systray icon" I have one instance of Vlc in the systray waiting, but after I trigger my script I get another instance which launches as usual..

Comment: @x-code I added on to my answer to show how to not duplicate the systray icon so that it is only running one instance instead.

Comment: works!.........