# Revert start-vlc-minimized-from-command-line

Tags: vlc, ubuntu-mate

I followed this, but I want to revert back.

But I can no longer access the settings on VLC.

How can I do that?

> [Start vlc minimized from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368236/start-vlc-minimized-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by uninstalling and re-installing vlc.